# Undefined Variable and Invalid argument supplied for foreach(Code igniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some problem with these codes. I already declared notification but the error keeps showing.

Here's my **code**

```
 public function view_notification($id,$token= ''){
        $this->isLoggedIn();


    $data_applicant = array(
            // get data using email
        'token' => $token,
        'applicant_info' => $this->model->getApplicantInfo($this->session->userdata('email'))->row(),
        'notifications' =>  $this->model->notification($this->session->userdata('email'))->result_array(),
        'notification' =>  $this->model->all_notification($this->session->userdata('email'))->result_array(),

    );



    if ($this->session->userdata('position_id') == '3') { // Applicant
        $this->load->view('includes/applicant_header', $data_applicant);
        $this->load->view('applicant/notification/notifation', $data_applicant);
    }

   }

 }
```

Under view:

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <?php foreach($notification as $noti): ?>


      <h3>From: Administrator</h3><h5><?=$noti['notif_content']?></h5><p><?=$noti['date']?></p>
    <hr>


      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Need help thanks!

Comment: make sure `$data_applicant['notification']` is not empty . check for empty in your view

Answer (score 0):

In your code PHP is not able to find any array named as `$notification` is is inside an array called `$data_applicant`

so please rewrite your for each as as

```
 <?php foreach($data_applicant['notification'] as $noti): ?>
```

This will work please try.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, I'm just new in codeigniter.